# Mocking the dialog box that requires callback to be passed

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, viewmodel

I am unit testing the method in view model which does not any argument and inside that method i have a showdialog mesaage box in the following format :

```
this.uiService.ShowDialog(ViewName.UnlockScriptPassswordDialog,
                          StudioViewName.MainWindow, passwordDictionary,
                          this.OnUnlockScriptSetCallBack, null);
```

I am using Moq to mock the method but the control when reached to dialog box returned and could not reaches to `OnUnlockScriptSetCallBack` method. Please suggest how to go inside `OnUnlockScriptSetCallBack` method from the unit test.

Comment: What is `OnUnlockScriptSetCallBack`? Is it boolean property, or method `Foo(int value)`, or some class? Same for other arguments. Show definition of `ShowDialog` method which you are trying to mock

Comment: its is a method like this : private void OnUnlockScriptSetCallBack(Dictionary<string, object> returnValues).  its is doing some computation and setting a flag inside it.

Comment: Please, add definition of `ShowDialog` method to question

Comment: private void OnUnlockScriptSetCallBack(Dictionary<string, object>returnValues)
{
if (returnValues != null && returnValues.Count > 0)
{
if (returnValues.ContainsKey("Operation")){
switch ((string)returnValues["Operation"]){
case "YESSCRIPTOPEN": // do nothing.
this.openPasswordProtectedScript = true;
break;
case "NOSCRIPTOPEN":this.openPasswordProtectedScript = false;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

Comment: Could you update the question to contain the function signature directly, instead of here in a comment?